# Align images on the same row regardless of window size

Tags: html, css, layout, window-resize

When I resize the window, the images don't align well. I am trying to get the bottom of each image to align with the end of the `.pinkDiv` *regardless of window size*.

Here's a screenshot of an image doesn't align well in a specific window size:

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
.pinkDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.miniDiv {
  width: calc(100% * 100 / 893);
  background-color: green;
}

.maxiDiv {
  width: calc(100% * 93 / 893);
  background-color: green;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 174px;
}

#queen {
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.tab2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: rgb(208, 49, 45, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="pinkDiv">
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style=" width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="maxiDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chess_piece_-_White_queen.jpg" style="width:100%"
      id="queen">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab2">
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the floats, and add `display:flex;` to `.pinkDiv` Maybe ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Just tried it!! Doesn't seem to work..

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean exactly ? Also isn't that what you wanted ? all images stay withing the pink div ?

Comment: I edited the main code according to the aforementioned suggestion.. the bottom of each image doesn't align with the bottom of the pink div when i resize the window

Comment: Oh yes add `align-items: flex-end;` to pink div and remove `margin-top: 174px;` from `img` also don't edit your question based on a suggestion, it defies the purpose

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem. I edited the question to show what I meant by doesn't work. I won't edit the question again to explain the issue with the latest addition but I will say that the original problem still exists

Comment: Problem solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

[image]

Added

```css
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
```

to `.pinkDiv`

---

Full code:

```css
.pinkDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 290px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.miniDiv {
  width: calc(100% * 100 / 893);
  background-color: green;
}

.maxiDiv {
  width: calc(100% * 93 / 893);
  background-color: green;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 174px;
}

#queen {
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.tab2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: rgb(208, 49, 45, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="pinkDiv">
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style=" width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="maxiDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chess_piece_-_White_queen.jpg" style="width:100%"
      id="queen">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="miniDiv">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/StauntonPawn2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab2">
</div>
```